# Date to LocalDateTime to DateTime using jodatime but how to add timezone

Tags: jodatime

I dont' care if it is MST or MDT, but I have a LocalDateTime object with the time(ie. no timezone).  I want to add MST or MDT and create a DateTime object such that I can get milliseconds since the epoch for storage and milliseconds from the epoch is in UTC of course just like System.currentTimeMillis is in UTC.

So is there a way to say MountainTime independent of savings or daylight time as it should know that from the date it has itself, correct?  How to do that?

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A LocalDateTime is just a bunch of numbers (day, month, year, hour, minute...) that represent a civil (not a physic) concept. A Datetime is instead a physical concept (an instant of time), which in addition has a Timezone, and hence, it can be expressed in day/month/year.

To convert from a LocalDateTime to a Datetime, you need to specify a Timezone. This conversion is not totally well defined, though; because at [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) transitions two different DateTimes can correspond to a same LocalDateTime.

Comment: so is there a way to get the DateTime if I have the date and time, and I know I am in MountainTime but I don't know if the time is daylight or standard...I guess I could code it according to the spec but was trying to avoid that.

Comment: MountainTime is a Timezone? (I'm not american)

Comment: There is MST and MDT which are Mountain Standard Time and Mountain Daylight Time.  The S and D just signify the hour change that happens in the fall and spring really as it is all mountain time.

Comment: I found I had to intermediately convert joda LocalDateTime to java.util.Date, and then to DateTime with time zone specified.  Not sure if its possible to directly convert, but this was good enough for me

Comment: @cellepo : should directly use [toDateTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDateTime.html)

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.now()                                      // Capture the current moment in UTC.
       .atZone( ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" ) )  // Adjust from UTC to the wall-clock time in use by the people of a particular region (a time zone).
```

…or…

```
ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" ) )
```

## java.time

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

## Use real time zones

Do not use `MST` or `MDT` or other such 3-4 letter abbreviations. They are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`.

If you meant the time zone just left of center of North America, specify a meaningful time zone such as `America/Edmonton`. Remember that Arizona has a different zone, having never adopted the nonsense of Daylight Saving Time; so there use `America/Phoenix`.

## `Instant` for UTC

If you want to work in UTC, which is often wise, use the `Instant` class. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();  // Current moment in UTC.
```

To generate a String in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, call `toString`.

```
String output = instant.toString();
```

> 2016-12-06T22:26:32.773Z

If you want a count of whole seconds since the epoch of `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`, call `getSeconds`.

```
long secondsSinceEpoch = instant.getSeconds();
```

For milliseconds since that same epoch, call `toEpochMilli`.

```
long milliseconds = instant.toEpochMilli();
```

I strongly recommend against handling date-time values as a count-from-epoch number. They are error-prone, difficult to debug as humans cannot discern a meaning from such numbers. Instead:

- Use java.time objects in your code.
- Use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formatted strings when serializing values.

## `ZonedDateTime`

To see that same moment through the lens of a region’s time zone, their [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time), apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Edmonton" ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instance.atZone( z );
```

Going the other direction, you can extract an `Instant` for a UTC value.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant();
```

## `LocalDateTime`

Your Question mentioned having a `LocalDateTime`. The `Local…` classes lack any time zone or offset information, purposely. So they do *not* represent a point on the timeline.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of( 2016 , 1 , 23 , 12 , 34 , 56 );
```

> ldt.toString(): 2016-01-23T12:34:56

Apply a time zone to produce a `ZonedDateTime`, giving real meaning to the value.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) );
```

> zdt.toString(): 2016-01-23T12:34:56-05:00[America/Montreal]

## Daylight Saving Time (DST)

> So is there a way to say MountainTime independent of savings or daylight time as it should know that from the date it has itself, correct?

You need not concern yourself with DST or other such anomalies. The java.time classes handle that for you automatically. But do **read the class doc** to understand the behavior during the DST cut-over (gaining or losing an hour or such) as well as when you may be asking for a wall-clock time that does not exist (during the time the clock "springs forward").

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Using a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later, you may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. No need for strings nor java.sql.* classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).